# EntityEvent of Azure Resource Provider for Windows Azure Store

Tags: .net, azure, azure-store

I'm implementing azure store provider like here https://github.com/MetricsHub/AzureStoreRP. Also I'm using SDK https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-resource-provider-sdk. There is sample request in SDK on https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-resource-provider-sdk/blob/master/docs/api-subscription.md

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EntityEvent>
    ...
</EntityEvent>
```

There is class with Namespace from sample https://github.com/MetricsHub/AzureStoreRP/blob/master/AzureStoreRP.Data/Contracts/EntityEvent.cs

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Cis.DevExp.Services.Rdfe.ServiceManagement")]
    public class EntityEvent : IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        ...
    }
```

When I send sdk sample's  request, I get exception

```
    <ExceptionMessage>Error in line 1 position 14. Expecting element 'EntityEvent'
     from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Cis.DevExp.Services.Rdfe.ServiceManagement'.. 
     Encountered 'Element'  with name 'EntityEvent', namespace ''.
        </ExceptionMessage>
```

Microsoft will test my RP in staging. But I don't know which namespace I should use. May be someone's implemented it?

Comment: The namespace name is the right one. Do you have a minimal shortest code snippet showing how exactly you send the request?

Comment: I send it from Dev Http (Google Chrome Extension) with attached xml file, that contains entity event without namespace. Problem with that SDK different from sample with sources. When I use this cs file and set explicit namespace http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Cis.DevExp.Services.Rdfe.ServiceManagement in xml, It works great. But In SDK is not setted explicit namespace.

Comment: What SDK do you mean?

Comment: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-resource-provider-sdk. There are descriptions of requests, that will be sent to the service that I'm trying to implement.

Comment: The "SDK" is rather incomplete - you'll be much better off sticking to how the sample at MetricsHub works.